# How do i read from a file C++ and output it

Tags: c++, linux

I tried to use getline

but it give me some error

note: __ssize_t getline(char**, size_t*, FILE*)

My line is like this

```
ofstream myfile;

myfile.open("file.txt");
while(!myfile.eof())
{
    getline(myfile,sline);
    cout << sline;
 }
```

How do i get my C++ to read file.txt

Comment: You didn’t post the actual error message. And then … yes, what Karoly said.

Comment: Use `ifstream` to read. `ofstream` is for writing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ensure you have `#include <string>`, where [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) is defined, and that `sline` is a `std::string`.

Change the structure of the loop to:

```
while (std::getline(myfile, sline))
{
    std::cout << sline << "\n";
}
```

to avoid processing a failed read.

Use [`std::ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) to read, not `std::ofstream` as pointed out by Karoly in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you `#include`d `<stdio.h>` or `<cstdio>` and are therefore trying to use C's `getline` function. Change:

```
getline(myfile,sline);
```

to:

```
std::getline(myfile,sline);
```

to ensure that you are using the C++ `getline`.